# How to programatically check if an SMB connection is encrypted?

Tags: c#, wmi, smb

In PowerShell:

```
PS> (Get-SmbConnection)[0].Encrypted
```

How do I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3):

That's a WMI method.  To do that in C#, you're going to have to write a whole lot of code.  Some links you will need to get started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc146163.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830461(v=vs.85).aspx.

Also note that you'll most likely have to include the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll`from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WMI\v1.0`.

Also note that the particular item you need is only available on windows 8/2012 and up.